# How do I unit test a classifier?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsx, classification

given the signature

```
 public IList<ClassificationSpan> GetClassificationSpans(SnapshotSpan span)
```

I've been tracing through properties and constructors of SnapshotSpan and haven't found anything that looks remotely possible to stub out for testing a classifier against say a string or a file.

How would I unit test a new VS2012 classifier?

Answer (score 0):

SnapshotSpan is a struct (i.e. a value type. ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.snapshotspan.aspx), it cannot be stubbed and shimmed.

IClassifier.GetClassificationSpans is an interface method and we're creating StubIClassifier class so you can stub IClassifier. As to parameter ClassificationSpan, we created a ShimClassificationSpan class which you can use to shim it.

For a detail on using Fakes in VS2012, please ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx.

Regards,

Patrick Tseng - Visual Studio ALM team.